# Image inside marker callout is cut React Native

Tags: react-native, google-maps, google-maps-markers, react-native-maps, callouts

The image inside the Callout in Map View (google map) wont display the whole image.

[image: imagecut]

At first, there is no image displaying in the callout. so I change my code, putting the image inside the . Now the image is present, but I am stuck on showing the whole image to display inside the callout.

```
return (
    <Marker key={index} coordinate={{latitude: shops.lat, longitude: shops.lng,
    latitudeDelta: 0.007, longitudeDelta: 0.005}} image={require('../assets/images/pin1.png')}
    >
        <Callout style={{height:100, width:100}}>
        <Text>{shops.name}</Text>
        <Text className='bg-sky-100'>
            <Image style={{width:90, height:90}} source={shops.image} />  
        </Text>
        </Callout>
    </Marker>
)
```

this is the source for the image

```
image: require('../assets/images/purewater.png'),
```

Comment: Are you using any libraries for this? Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that the community can help you better. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution works for me.

```
<Marker key={index} coordinate={{
    latitude: parseFloat(shop.shops.latitude), longitude: parseFloat(shop.shops.longitude),
    latitudeDelta: 0.007, longitudeDelta: 0.005
}}
>
    <Image source={require('../assets/images/pin1.png')} style={{ height: 30, width: 30 }} />
    <Callout style={{ height: 150, width: 160 }}
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Shop', { ...shop.shops })}
        onPressOut={() => dispatch(emptyShopData())}
    >
        <Text className='bg-sky-100 h-36 w-36 flex-1 -mt-24 mx-2'>
            <Image resizeMode={'cover'} style={{ width: 150, height: 150 }} 
            src={
                shop.shops.photo !== '' ? 
                PublicBaseURL + 'uploads/' + shop.shops.user_id + '/' + shop.shops.photo
                : PublicBaseURL + 'assets/img/no-image.png'
            } />
        </Text>
        <View className='flex-row'>
            <Text className='font-bold'>{shop.shops.business_name} · </Text>
            <Text className='text-sm text-green-600'>{shop.shops.distance.toFixed(1)} km</Text>
        </View>
        <Text className='italic text-sm'>Tap for more details</Text>
    </Callout>
</Marker>
```

Basically it needed to be manually adjust to fit your setup.
Adding styling for the `<Text className='bg-sky-100 h-36 w-36 flex-1 -mt-24 mx-2'>` which matches the size of the Callout. And finally, setting style for the image `<Image resizeMode={'cover'} style={{ width: 150, height: 150 }}  src={...}`

Note: i used nativewind for styling

Legend:

`h-36 w-36 -mt-24 mx-2` is equivalent to

```
height: 144px,
width: 144px,
margin-top: -96,
margin-left: 8px,
margin-right: 8px
```

[image: final outcome]

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the prop `resizeMode={'contain'}` to your `<Image />` and replace the `<Text>` container by a `<View>`:

```js
return (
    <Marker key={index} coordinate={{latitude: shops.lat, longitude: shops.lng,
    latitudeDelta: 0.007, longitudeDelta: 0.005}} image={require('../assets/images/pin1.png')}
    >
        <Callout style={{height:100, width:100}}>
        <Text>{shops.name}</Text>
        <View className='bg-sky-100'>
            <Image resizeMode={'contain'} style={{width:90, height:90}} source={shops.image} />  
        </View>
        </Callout>
    </Marker>
)
```

Comment: I tried adding the given code, and the image was gone, leaving only the background color.